# Forward message (album) telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I'm trying to forward a message with a group of photos. But they are redirected by separate messages in destination channel. How can I redirect with one message?

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, chats=FROM))
async def handler_frw(event):
    await client.forward_messages(CHANNEL_TO, event.message)
```

If I use "send_message" it send as one message.
But TO_NAME - doesn't work with id Channel, only name :(
And i need "Forward from" in destination channel.

```
@client.on(events.Album(chats=FROM))
async def handler_snd(event):
    print("Have album.")
    caps = []
    for item in event.messages:
        caps.append(item.message)
    await client.send_message(TO_NAME, file=event.messages, message=caps)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to forward the whole album, utilize the corresponding Album event instead of the New Message event. Telethon supposedly does the necessary hacks to collect the single messages together.

[See the docu](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.album.Album)

```
from telethon import events

@events.register(events.Album)
async def albumHandler(self, event):
    # Forwarding the album as a whole to some chat
    event.forward_to(chat)
```