# Telethon (or Pyrogram) forward whole album instead of last media without caption

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

I'm trying to forward *any* last message from a specififc channel using Telethon's `client.iter_messages(channel_id, limit=1)` and `message.forward_to(group_id)`

**The problem is if the message is an album, only the last image of the album gets forwarded. Also caption is not included.**

The exact same thing happens with Pyrogram's `app.get_chat_history(channel_id, limit=1)` and `message.forward(group_id)`

The problem itself, I suppose, lies in the way ids work for media in albums.
I need a way to somehow forward the whole message.

**Note: I am aware of Telethon's `events.Album` but don't see any way to implement it in my case. Also this ([Forward message (album) telethon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440069/forward-message-album-telethon)) somehow relates to my problem but again I don't know how to make it work properly. Also `if message.grouped_id:` might help.**

Code (Telethon variant):

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient('telethon-client', api_id, api_hash)


async def main():
    async for message in client.iter_messages(test_channel_id, limit=1):
        await message.forward_to(test_group_id)


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is if the message is an album, only the last image of the album gets forwarded. Also caption is not included.

This is because albums are in fact separate messages. "The last message" is the last photo of the album, and clients often put the caption in the first image of the album.

> The problem itself, I suppose, lies in the way ids work for media in albums. I need a way to somehow forward the whole message.

You are correctly forwarding the "whole" message. The problem is you want to forward multiple messages at the same time.

> Also if message.grouped_id: might help

Yes, you can use that to detect what messages belong to the same group. An album consists of up to ten messages that share the `grouped_id`.

You can do something like this:

```py
current_album = None
current_group_id = None

async for message in client.iter_messages(test_channel_id):
    if current_group_id and message.grouped_id != current_group_id:
        print('Group finished:', current_group_id, 'had', len(current_album))
        current_group_id = None
        current_album = None

    if not current_group_id and message.grouped_id:
        print('New group:', message.grouped_id)
        current_group_id = message.grouped_id
        current_album = []

    if current_group_id:
        current_album.append(message)
```

This will tell you how many messages are found in a group. Note that it is possible for messages that have a `grouped_id` to be interleaved with messages that don't (so **the above code can fail**):

- msg_id 1001, grouped_id 4001
- msg_id 1002, grouped_id None
- msg_id 1003, grouped_id 4001

is possible, and the code will detect the 4001 album twice, each time with one message. You can adapt the code to attempt to handle this. It is not possible to determine an album's length beforehand, you just need to fetch more messages to find out if they're in the same group.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed answer. But this method will require "building" the message and then `send_message` at the end 
 so it is actually a copy of the message? Forwarding whole album will require forwarding multiple messages in one message which is impossible? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: When you forward multiple messages in the same forward call, if they all belong to the same album, the album will be kept.